# Why doesn't Gardening & Landscaping have a banner image?

Tags: discussion, design

Some other SE groups I'm part of, eg. Bicycles has a colorful themed background behind it. Presumably they can only be a good thing, making the site look more professional and retaining users. 
 How would the gardening and landscaping group go about designing and choosing a background?

Comment: Do you mean as a background image for the space already allocated above the question title and below the black, without removing the links? IMO, few sites on the Internet have memorable/significant banner images. They were popular in the late 90's, but I haven't seen much of them (by *comparison*) for years. They can potentially take up vertical space, too, which may bother utilitarians, if they're not really thin banners with integrated menus or something. However, the site already looks equipped to handle a banner there, if we keep the stuff that is there on it and visible.

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our Community Managers from last week: [Custom Gardening & Landscaping design and logo - Information gathering](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/961/37696) :)

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/982/37696)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All SE "Beta Sites" are displayed in the Blueprint theme. When the site graduates then it can produce and display it's own unique design. If you would like to get involved, this [Meta Discussion](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/321/11461) would be a good place to start.